# CentOS 7 set grub2 default boot menu

Tags: centos7, grub

I installed CentOS 7 with kernel 4. It defaulted to kernel 4 after installing it and gave me the option to boot to the original option. But then after yum updated the packaged kernel it changed the default to the updated packaged kernel. I wanted to leave the updated packaged kernel as an option but still boot to kernel 4.

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming?

Answer (score -1):

Updating the grub file directly using nano had no effect. It wasn't until I used grub2-set-default to select the menu item I wanted it to boot from did it work.